# Full screen image view while hiding the status bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uistatusbar

I am making a full screen image view that is zoomable and scrollable similar to the one in Twitter for iPhone.  I have it almost the same except I cant figure out how to use the real estate under the stats bar.

I start with a UINavigationController and push my image view.  My image view is a UIView that contains a UIScrollView with a frame of (0, -44, 320, 480) to put it beneath the navigation bar, and a UIImageView on top of that with a frame of the scroll view's bounds.

I am hiding the navigation bar and status bar using:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.0f];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

They hide correctly, but I am left with 20px of black at the top.  I tried setting the scroll view's frame y-origin to -66, but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but have you tried setting the status bar to black transparent?

Comment: Tried setting it to transparent, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

if u select the view in Interface Builder and go to attribute inspector, make sure those are bars are set to none.

Comment: this should be easily fixable in IB.  but that comment didnt help alavoil so im not sure, if you want to post your project somewhere ill take a look but other than my original comment idk what else to offer without seeing the project (or at least a simplified version (to hide code you dont want public))

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to hide status bar

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
return YES;
}
```

Also in the viewWillAppear() method, set the navigation bar hidden :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```